# mint 13 xfce: geforce fx 5500 "not new enough to support nvidia-settings display configuration page

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia, graphics, x-server

I have a Geforce FX 5500 graphics card and so far, It has not worked properly in my Linux Mint 13 XFCE installation.

I have tried several solutions to get the graphics card working but nothing helped. I have searched the internet for solutions and tried them. (including the experimental 310 driver).

After installing the experimental 310 driver (?) I saw the boot animation for the first time since I installed Linux Mint.

I have tried every single driver that was available in the 'additional drivers' screen. Nothing worked.

I have tried to download and install the drivers directly from the nvidia website but I could not manage to get this install (had to do it as root, I tried, but everytime there was something wrong).

I am running *Linux mint 13 XFCE* now (considering to install the latest mint LTS release, or try Elementary OS (hoping that with Elementary OS the card works out of the box properly).

But does someone have a solution for me?

No matter what I try, everytime, in Nvidia X Server Settings, the X display screen tells me: the nvidia driver is not new enough to... etc. see image below (not my screen, but same error):

[image: nvidia x server display]

Answer (score 0):

From the error message I would guess that means that the "diver is not new enough to support the nvidia-settings page"

This is none too surprising since the GFX 5 series is over 10 years old which is like 80 in human years. The amazing bit is that nVidia maintained driver support for that antique through 2008.

Comment: ok, so no support for older graphics cards I understand. I guess windows was not so bad at all...

Comment: I used to think Linux was such a nice solution for older computers, but your answer implies te opposite. My computer perfectly suits my needs but my Linux distro cannot work with my graphics card. That is much of a bummer for me. I am now wondering if this applies to every linux distro or not.